# Create / Update Resources via Rails 5 API with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I have a Match model with 2 players fields that have a belongs_to association with the User model

Model

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :player1, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'player1'
  belongs_to :player2, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'player2'

end
```

When creating a Match via the API (using a Postman POST request) I tried passing the user_id of the players but got a TypeMismatch error indicating the controller expected a User object but got a Fixnum.

Looking at this line:

```
@match = Match.new(match_params)
```

the error makes sense, so I modified my default scaffold generated controllers to look like this instead:

```
def create
  @match = Match.new
  @match.player1 = User.find(params[:match][:player1])
  @match.player2 = User.find(params[:match][:player2])

  if @match.save
    render json: @match, status: :created, location: @match
  else
    render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /matches/1
def update
  if @match.update( :player1 => User.find(params[:match][:player1]),
                    :player2 => User.find(params[:match][:player2])
                    )

    render json: @match
  else
    render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

It works, but the solution seems "inelegant".
Is there a better way to pass values to a controller with a belongs_to association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try changing your foreign_key in Match model from `player1, player2` to `player1_id, player2_id` respectively, via database migrations. Because your foreign_key and belongs_to associations are same? Please let me know whether it works!

Comment: And of course, please **update the parameters passed from views to controller**, probably player1 to player1_id, player2 to player2_id.

Comment: So obvious in retrospect Thanks, this worked perfectly with default match_params construct